# Rails 4 - Paperclip is not uploading files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am testing an Rails 4 application in localhost which uses Paperclip, and even though submitting images creates entries in the Database, the images folder is always empty.

**Model**

```
class Tile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game

    # Paperclip
    has_attached_file :image,
        styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
        url: "/images/:style/:filename",
        default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Controller**

```
class TilesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_game

    def create
        tile = @game.tiles.create tile_params
        redirect_to @game, notice: tile
    end

    private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_game
            @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def tile_params
            params.require(:tile).permit(:image)
        end
end
```

**View form**

```
<%= form_for([@game, Tile.new], multipart: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Everytime I try to print `<p><%= tile.image.url %></p>` I get `/images/original/missing.png`.

Why is this?

**Update**

- I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
- Imagemagick is installed.

Comment: Please show your controller create/update action and the form view

Comment: hi if you simply follow this you will be fine : https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: your view may wana look something like this : <%= image_tag @tile.image.url(:medium) %>

Comment: I added the controller

Comment: Can you add the view for the form as well?

Comment: I have added the view with the Form

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to also update `path` long with `url`, ie

```
has_attached_file :image,
    styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
    path: "/images/:style/:filename",
    url: "/images/:style/:filename",
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

As explained in [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip?autoplay=true) Railscasts ~5:20, `url` sets where images will be retrieved from, and `path` sets where they will be stored.

Comment: You are correct, but it is not the current issue author is experiencing right now - url being `...missing` clearly shows that file was not stored at all yet

Comment: Mmm that's true - I'll wait till he posts his controller/view as you requested in your comment, but leave this up in the meantime since he'll probably want to fix it as well at some point.

Comment: I added the controller

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `window`, to show image on the screen: `image_tag(tile.image.url(:small))`

Also, did you install `ImageMagick and file for Windown?'`

and if yes, did you set your environment to:  `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'` in the `config/environments/development.rb`? then restart your server.